# SML Function and Tuples

Tags: list, function, tuples, sml, ml

The SML function map takes a function and a list and it applies the function on the elements of the list.

The function map, which has the following type, is both polymorphic and higher order function.

```
fun map f [] = [] | map f (x::xs) = (f x)::(map f xs) 
val it = fn : (’a -> ’b) -> ’a list -> ’b list
```

Write another function mymap that takes two functions f and g and a list of 2-element tuples.

It applies f on the first element of the tuples and it applies g on the second element of the tuples.

For example:

```
- fun sqr x = x* x;
val sqr = fn : int -> int
- fun cube x:real = x*x*x;
val cube = fn : real -> real
- mymap sqr cube [(1,2.0),(2,3.0),(3,4.0),(4,5.0)];
```

**I don't know how to used first function map and i need hint for second function mymap**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
fun mymap f g l =
    let 
       fun  f1 f (h,h1) = (f(h),h1)

       fun  g1 g (h,h1) = (h,g(h1))
    in
        map (g1 g) (map (f1 f) l)
    end
```

We define two functions f1,g1 which have tuple as argument so that we could use map with f1 and list of tuples and same for g1.

Example:

```
- mymap sqr sqr [(4,9),(4,16),(9,4)];
val it = [(16,81),(16,256),(81,16)] : (int * int) list
```